# React custom TextInput control not able to type anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have a control MyCustomTextInput as follows

```
function MyCustomTextInput (props)
 return {
    <div>
       <TextInput
            value={props.value} </TextInput>
    </div>
}
```

This MyCustomTextInput is used on form as follows

```
<td>
   <MyCustomTextInput value="MyModelClass.MyName"> </MyCustomTextInput>
</td>
<td>
   <MyCustomTextInput value="MyModelClass.MyAddress"> </MyCustomTextInput>
</td>
```

The issue I am having is - I can see the MyName and MyAddress loaded into the custom control BUT I CANNOT TYPE ANYTHING in the text control

Could you please let me know what I am missing here

Appreciate your help

Comment: I am not familiar with React Native, but [to use Form and Inputs with vanilla React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html), I must create a state for the input, and apply `setState` in the `onChange` attribute of the `Input` element. It seems like you are missing `onChange` handler, that's why your inputs are not reacting and re-rendering when you type. See the docs I linked for more info.

Comment: You aren't changing the value `onChange` You need to manage state for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks a little bit strange, so I made a few changes in it. The first thing is that you should put your value into defaultValue attribute in text input field. So it should look like:

```
function MyCustomTextInput (props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <textarea defaultValue={props.value}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The next thing is that I recommend you to have components state for form elements like textarea, input, etc... So I would make it look like:

```
function MyCustomTextInput (props) {
    const [textareaValue, setTextareaState] = useState(props.value);
    const handleTextareaChange = (event) => setTextareaState(event.target.value);

    return (
        <div>
            <textarea defaultValue={textareaValue} onChange={handleTextareaChange}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
}
```